# Are the real and imaginary parts of orthogonal complex vectors linearly independent of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be some $n$ orthogonal complex vectors, i.e. $v_k = a_k + ib_k$ for some real vectors $a_k,b_k$. Is then the set $\{a_1,b_1,\dots,a_n,b_n\}$ linearly independent, i.e. are the real and imaginary parts of the $v_n$s linearly independent of each other? We know that $$0 = \left<v_k,v_l\right> = \left<a_k + ib_k,a_l + ib_l\right> = \left<a_k, a_l\right>  - i\left<a_k,b_l\right> + i\left<b_k,a_l\right> + \left<b_k, b_l\right>$$

which doesn't necessarily imply that e.g. $\left<a_k, a_l\right> = 0$. But then again, the only examples that come to my mind are e.g. Fourier bases in $L^2$, where this claim is true.

Comment: What if you consider the case of $n$ purely real vectors, linearly independent and orthogonal over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, or over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample:
$$v_1=(1,0)+i(1,1)$$
$$v_2=(1,0)+i(1,-2)$$